# Exponential Smoothing : Plotting SSE vs Alpha

Tags: time-series, smoothing

I am able to run the below code:

```
fit1 <- ses(books[,1], alpha=0.99, initial="simple", h=4) #provide alpha manually

sse = sum((books[,1] - fitted(fit1))) # the one-step-ahead within-sample forecast errors
```

On the back of the above code, I wanted to create 100 objects and tried using for loop (below code).

```
for(i in seq(0,1,by=0.01))
{

paste("fit", i, sep = "_") <- ses(books[,1], alpha=i, initial="simple", h=4) #provide alpha manually

paste("sse", i, sep = "_") = sum((books[,1] - fitted(paste("fit", i, sep = "_")))) # the one-step-ahead within-sample forecast errors
}
```

I am getting the following error,

```
**Error in paste("fit", i, sep = "_") <- ses(books[, 1], alpha = i, initial = "simple",  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object**
```

The above code is to create multiple objects fit_0.01,fit_0.02....

Can this loop work ?

Comment: what programming language is that? it looks R.

Comment: Yes, it is R language. I have this Time series data called books. I am trying to plot SSE vs alpha values in exponential smoothing

Answer (score 0):

You can get the loop to perform the way you asked with the `assign` operator:

```
for(i in seq(0, 1, by=0.1)) {
   assign(paste("fit", i, sep = "_"), ses(books[,1], alpha=i, initial="simple", h=4))
}
```